# create a batch to open iexplore and close another process after iexplore is closed

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that will first starts an apache webserver then launches iexplore to a specific page.  Now what I would like to happen is when the iexplore window closes it will also kill the apache process.

current batch file code:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq apache.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "apache.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" start apache.exe

start /wait iexplore http://localhost:8081/
taskkill /im apache.exe
```

This works great if I don't currently have any iexplore processes running but if ie is already running it immediately closes apache instead of waiting for IE to close first.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop until there are no more `iexplore.exe` processes:

```
:loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" /nh | find /i "iexplore.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
  goto loop
)
```

The ping is for waiting 1 second before trying again (on Win7 you can replace it with the `timeout` command).

However, I think you'd be better off using a more versatile scripting language.

Comment: This worked well!  I had to change neq to 1 instead of 0 though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'd recommend making the condition `equ 0`, though (loop as long as an `iexplore.exe` process is found).